# Optimized and efficient way to sort int[] primitive array in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I did a lot of research into sorting int[] primitive array in descending order, but most methods suggest creating an ArrayList and then using Collections.sort().

Currently, I have tried:

```
    int arr[] = new int[] {1,5,6,3,2};
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
```

This is O(nlogn) time complexity and O(1) space.

Can I do this in less code and as efficiently using a custom compare() function? If so, how? I ask for less code, because I'd like to be able to write it quickly in coding competitions / interviews! Thanks!

UPDATE: I understand that the time and space complexities are the best they can get, but is it possible to sort the array in less lines of code. For example, by using a custom compare/ lambda function/ etc?

Comment: If you think about it, an array sorted in ascending order is really the same as one in descending order. It's just that, to access index `x`, you need to access `length - x - 1` :-)

Comment: @Sweeper huh... that's a really good point actually! I didn't think about it like that! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of "researching" by googling for example code, I suggest you research by getting a good textbook on data structures and algorithms that covers sorting, and use the knowledge that you get by reading the book to code reverse sort for yourself.  (A really good textbook would contain a *proof* that O(nlogn) time complexity in O(1) space cannot be bettered.)

Comment: Aside: if interviewers are going to judge you on your ability to quickly code an optimal sort algorithm from scratch, they are completely missing the point.  It is not a useful specific skill, and not indicative of any advanced programming or problem solving ability.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for your comment! For sure, but in the question I did say "as efficiently"... I was hoping to find a way in less code to sort an int[] array in Java (for example, using a lambda function/custom compare/etc. I really appreciate your responses!

Comment: @StephenC Agreed, I meant as a part of a larger problem where I would need to sort an int[] array in descending order. I just wanted to know how I can do it quickly (lines of code-wise) so that I don't waste time.

Comment: How many elements?  Because for length=5, it really doesn't matter what you choose.  I'm not sure where it would start to matter.  *When in doubt, use brute force* - Ken Thompson.  The crucial point is that big-O time complexity is in "steps", and if your "steps" get more costly, it's not an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you code has a few issues with the 2nd and 3rd line of the for loop, since the first index it tries to access is "6", which doesn't exist. The last line of the for loop has an extra `]`

So, I think this is what you meant, feel free to correct me if I've got this wrong!

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length / 2; i++) {
     int temp = arr[i];
     arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
     arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
 }
```

But if you want to maintain lower space complexity, I think the in-place modification you have is pretty close to as small as you're going to get. Even with streams, it's not going to get much shorter (but will get somewhat subjectively messier).

Also, not to complicate things further, but if your array uses a sufficiently small range (edit: and more importantly, you know that range beforehand), you can use [counting sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/), which is O(n+k) time complexity vs. `Arrays.sort()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to reduce the number of lines of code? By using a lambda function, custom compare, etc. Maybe something like Arrays.sort(arr, Compare<>())?

Comment: Not that I'd really recommend in any actual setting, but from a purely 'academic' perspective - ```final int[] i = {0}; arr = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sorted((a,b) -> Integer.compare(b,a)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();``` (I'm sure there are ways to make it better, I'm a relative newbie to streams). 
As you can see, this boxes and unboxes and ignores the optimization of ```Arrays.sort```, so you're possibly losing a lot more than just extra characters here.

Answer (score 2):

O(nlogn) time and O(1) space is the theoretical best result for sorting things. No, you can't algorithmically sort faster. You can, as usual, speed things up a bit without algorithmic improvement, but such gains are generally tiny, fleeting, and dependent on the architecture you run it on and the phase of the moon.

Short of copying the code from Arrays.sort just to reverse the direction, you can't optimize away the O(n) run to reverse the array, though you can, as Sweeper suggested in a comment, update the rest of the code to reverse the index used to look things up.